# How to change projection for L.imageOverlay in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, gis, epsg

I want to use `L.imageOverlay` to show global temperature, my current image looks like the one below:

[image]

But when i overlay it using leaflet it shows like this:

[image]

Maybe it because wrong projection, this is my code:

```
L.imageOverlay('./tt.png',
    [[90, -180], [90, 180], [-90, 180], [-90, -180]],
    {opacity: 0.5, autoZIndex: true,interactive: true}
).addTo(map);
```

I think the problem is the conversion from  Equirectangular to  Mercator square projection, but i don't know how to fix that.